# Center align li with equal height and fixed width

Tags: html, css

Under an ul, there are 5 li's. wanted to have all the li with same height with fixed width(20% for each li is 100%). i have achieved that with the below code.But my problem is, if i have only 3 or 4 li's i want to display the li's with same height and width but in center. Right now if i have 3 or 4, the width is adjusting and occupying the whole ul container.

Even if its 3 li or 4 li, the li should have fixed width with aligned in the center.

```css
.box-outer {
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  background-color: #333;
}

.boxes {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 10% !important;
  margin-right: 1% !important;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 32px 29px;
  display: table-cell;
}

.field-number {
  color: #de008d;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.field-text {
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-outer">
  <div class="boxes">
    <h4 class="field-number">83</h4>
    <span class="field-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,</span>
  </div>
  <div class="boxes">
    <h4 class="field-number">7,800</h4><span class="field-text">mod tempor incididunt ut labor</span>
  </div>
  <div class="boxes">
    <h4 class="field-number">65k</h4><span class="field-text">ut aliquip</span>
  </div>
  <div class="boxes">
    <h4 class="field-number">37k</h4><span class="field-text">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="boxes">
    <h4 class="field-number">&#163;250m</h4><span class="field-text">veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/iprameshkumar/18pmzb6f/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **flexbox**.
Just create a container with

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: stretch;
```

and set your inner boxes with

```
flex: 0 0 20%;
display: flex;
align-items: center
```

Like this each element has 20% width of the container, regardless how many they are, and are always centered in the container. Obviously, the sixth would wrap on a second line but still centered.

Comment: you are missing the vertical-alignement for the children's content ;)

Comment: You're right, i had not read that part. I corrected the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the flex box to achieve the same. Here is a sample code having 5 li's

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20%;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Li 1</li>
  <li>Li 2</li>
  <li>Li 3</li>
  <li>Li 4</li>
  <li>Li 5</li>
</ul>
```

Here is another sample code having 3 li's:

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20%;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Li 1</li>
  <li>Li 2</li>
  <li>Li 5</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS is same, only the number of li's are different.

Comment: you are also missing the vertical-alignement for the children's content ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr, that is true and can be done too, but that wasn't the main aim of this question, if you want I can add a note in the answer. This answer is totally specific to the objective of the question.

Comment: the question is about a layout build on table-layout, vertical-alignement in cells is one of the main reason to use it beside cells of same height. cells of same height can be build from table, flex or grid display. ;) but only table allows vertical-alignement without inbricating the display layout chosen. We might help the op explaining about this differences about displays and how to master alignement within the children. Else i have no idea why table was chosen in the first place ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use Flexbox:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box-outer {   
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: #333;
}
.boxes {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.field-number {
  color: #de008d;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: "hurme_geometric_sans_4regular", sans-serif;
}
.field-text {
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-outer">
  <div class="boxes">
    <h4 class="field-number">67</h4>
    <span class="field-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,</span>
  </div>
  <div class="boxes">
    <h4 class="field-number">7,800</h4>
    <span class="field-text">mod tempor incididunt ut labor</span>
  </div>
  <div class="boxes">
    <h4 class="field-number">6k</h4>
    <span class="field-text">ut aliquip</span>
  </div>
  <div class="boxes">
    <h4 class="field-number">7k</h4>
    <span class="field-text">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="boxes">
    <h4 class="field-number">775m</h4>
    <span class="field-text">veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `display: flex;` instead of `table`.

With that and on the first box `margin-left: auto;` and on the last box `margin-right: auto;`, a fixed `width` on each box, it will stay the same everytime.

You can also play with `min-width: 10%` and `width: min-content` on the boxes for other sizings/responsiveness to the content but not filling.

Your fiddle, updated: https://jsfiddle.net/vhkw6y7o/

```css
 .box-outer {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .boxes {
    border: 1px dotted red;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    width: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .boxes:first-child {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  .boxes:last-child {
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .field-number {
    color: #de008d;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
  .field-text {
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: #fff;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**if you want to keep using the `table-layout`**, you will need to get the container centered itself, the row is always entirely filled.

`width` is to be set directly to the cell(`.boxes`) so that you have 1 or 5, it will be the size set and the table(`.box-outer`) will center itself.

This means you cannot set the table(`.box-outer`) to `width:100%` and benefit from the `table-layout:fixed;` algorythm.
The cells(`.boxes`) will grow if the content is wider than the `width` set (this is the table-layout behavior).

the only benefit you get here, is that every boxes will be the same height and most of the time the same width.

Also, `table-cell` do not accept `margin`, you need to set `border-spacing` on the `table` parent displayed instead.

some fix of your code, keeping the `display: table` / `table-cell` , rules could be :

```css
.box-outer {
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;/* useless if no width set */
  background-color: #333;
  margin: auto;/* update */
  border-spacing: 0.5vw 0;/* update */
}

.boxes {
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* removed: 
  width: 10% !important; ?? this allows 10 boxes ?
  margin-right: 1% !important; :( doesn't work on a cell .
  */
  width: 20vw;/* update  whatever value, it is equal to min-width in this table-layout */
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 32px 29px;
  display: table-cell;
}

.field-number {
  color: #de008d;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.field-text {
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-outer">
  <div class="boxes">
    <h4 class="field-number">83</h4>
    <span class="field-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,</span>
  </div>
  <div class="boxes">
    <h4 class="field-number">7,800</h4><span class="field-text">mod tempor incididunt ut labor</span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>Your 5 boxes: it breaks on small screen
<hr>
<div class="box-outer">
  <div class="boxes">
    <h4 class="field-number">83</h4>
    <span class="field-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,</span>
  </div>
  <div class="boxes">
    <h4 class="field-number">7,800</h4><span class="field-text">mod tempor incididunt ut labor</span>
  </div>
  <div class="boxes">
    <h4 class="field-number">65k</h4><span class="field-text">ut aliquip</span>
  </div>
  <div class="boxes">
    <h4 class="field-number">37k</h4><span class="field-text">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="boxes">
    <h4 class="field-number">&#163;250m</h4><span class="field-text">veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

On the other side, every body tells you about flex, which can be more flexible and also different.

flex can be inbricated to let you have `.boxes` of same `height` but also  allow vertical and horizontal centering of their content.*(maybe, at this point, you'll be thinking about dropping the `display:table` method)*

here is an example:

```css
.box-outer {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #333;
  justify-content:center;
  /* flex-wrap:wrap; *//* to allow boxes to wrap to next line(s) */
}

.boxes {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 1 16.5%;/* 5 boxes + margins tune this to your needs  */
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 32px 29px;
  margin: 1% 0.5%;/*tune to your needs, Note: vertical margin/padding in % is calculated from width */
}

.field-number {
  color: #de008d;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.field-text {
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<p>5 boxes on small screen breaks too with flex, you may want to allow wrapping ? Less than 5 boxes is to be seen below </p>
<div class="box-outer">
  <div class="boxes">
    <h4 class="field-number">83</h4>
    <span class="field-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,</span>
  </div>
  <div class="boxes">
    <h4 class="field-number">7,800</h4><span class="field-text">mod tempor incididunt ut labor</span>
  </div>
  <div class="boxes">
    <h4 class="field-number">65k</h4><span class="field-text">ut aliquip</span>
  </div>
  <div class="boxes">
    <h4 class="field-number">37k</h4><span class="field-text">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="boxes">
    <h4 class="field-number">&#163;250m</h4><span class="field-text">veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="box-outer">
  <div class="boxes">
    <h4 class="field-number">83</h4>
    <span class="field-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,</span>
  </div>
  <div class="boxes">
    <h4 class="field-number">7,800</h4><span class="field-text">mod tempor incididunt ut labor </span>
  </div>
  <div class="boxes">
    <h4 class="field-number">65k</h4><span class="field-text">ut aliquip</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Usefull tutorial or reminder about the flex model : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/